# How to fail a java.util.concurrent.Future

Tags: java, vert.x, completable-future

There is pretty heavy use of `io.vertx.core.Future` in the vertx ecosystem:
https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html

An example of using Vertx `Future` is here:

```
private Future<Void> prepareDatabase() {

  Future<Void> future = Future.future();

  dbClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject(...));

  dbClient.getConnection(ar -> {    

    if (ar.failed()) {
      LOGGER.error("Could not open a database connection", ar.cause());
      future.fail(ar.cause());  // here
      return; 
    } 

    SQLConnection connection = ar.result();   
    connection.execute(SQL_CREATE_PAGES_TABLE, create -> {
        connection.close();   
        if (create.failed()) {
          future.fail(create.cause());  // here
        } else {
          future.complete();  
        }
     });
  });

  return future;
}
```

I was under the impression that `io.vertx.core.Future` had something to do with `java.util.concurrent.Future`, but it appears that it doesn't. As you can see the way to tell a Vertx future to fail is to call it's fail() method.

On the other hand, we have CompletableFuture which is an implementation of the `java.util.concurrent.Future` interface:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

I don't see a fail method on the CompletableFuture, I only see "resolve()".

So my guess is that the only way to fail a CompletableFuture is to throw an Exception?

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("fail this future");
    return "This would be the success result";
});
```

besides throwing an error, is there a way to "fail" a CompletableFuture?
In other words, using a Vertx Future, we just call f.fail(), but what about with a CompletableFuture?

Comment: There is a `completeExceptionally` method, and the related `obtrudeException`.

Comment: yikes not shooting the messenger but those are some bizarre names, can you show an example of how to use them? Harder to find good examples online than I would have thought.

Comment: Sigh... CompletableFuture is *almost* the thing I would want to use, except that it's broken in so many ways. I remember when I saw the API for the first time and saw things like "obtrude"... ugh.

Comment: Yeah the vertx Future API seems a lot more sane

Answer (score 2):

`CompletableFuture` encourages you to throw exceptions from `supplyAsync()` method to describe failures.

As mentioned in the comments, there's also `completeExceptionally()` method, which you can use in case you have a `Future` at hand, and would like to fail it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-

Since Java9, there's also `CompletableFuture.failedFuture​(Throwable ex)` construct, if you want to return an already failed future.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture-java.lang.Throwable-